# pdf black and white compression without losing text recognition

Tags: pdf, compression, size

I'm looking for a way to reduce the size of various pdf archives that I have. I have tested lot of programs and mechanisms. I get the best results with the following secuence:

```
pdfimages -png file.pdf image
```

then I work on these images with `scantailor` (GUI) to reduce resolution and convert all pages to black and white. Now I compress those with:

```
jbig2 -s -p -v *.jpg && pdf.py output > out.pdf
```

I get around x4-x5 size reduction with little quality loss. So far, so good. The problem is that I lose the OCR and notes in the proccess.

Is there any program or mechanism that can do all those steps: reduce the PDF resolution, convert it to black and white and compress it with `jbig2enc` without losing the text recognition and notes?

Comment: Please detail the commands you are using, especially for OCR, by editing your question. Otherwise it is very difficult to help.

Comment: I have specified now the commands and skipped the use of a OCR program to make it simpler. It mantains the essential of the question. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the key problem is that you create a new PDF file. It would be better to find a tool to edit the images but keep the rest (OCR and meta data), or to dump that data and re-create your PDF with that data. Perhaps `pdftk` can help?  I have no file with OCR data so I cannot test whether `pdftk` can dump it. Also, as a note: if JPEG images are included in your files they will first be unpacked to PNG, then re-encoded which may be suboptimal for quality and compression/noise ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Ned64. I think it is a good idea looking for methods of mantaining the meta data. I will research that!